# If I load content dynamically, does history.pushState() cause that content to be added to the browser cache?

Tags: html, browser, browser-history, pushstate

Here's what happens:

1. Page loads (a timeline view)
2. User scrolls down to the bottom
3. More timeline content is loaded via AJAX
4. The URL is set to a new value with history.pushState(). If this URL is accessed directly, it loads the timeline so that it includes all content that's been loaded dynamically so far.
5. The user clicks a link in the timeline
6. The user then clicks the back button in the browser.

My question: when the back button is pressed, will the browser do a fresh load of the url provided via pushState() (which may involve a large performance hit if they have gone a long way down the timeline)? I'm hoping that instead it will update its page cache somehow when pushState() is called to include the DOM with the dynamic content added, and then reload that instead.

If it doesn't do any automatic cache magic like that, is there any way to make it do so in order to improve performance? It seems wasteful to reload a large number of posts every time the user clicks away from the timeline. Also, as they scroll, the URL is constantly updated so it would be a fresh load of all posts every time they click away, not even using normal browser caching.

I've looked for information, but can't seem to find anything that says how pushState() modifies the cache, if at all.

Comment: The history API only adds entries to the history, it has nothing to do with caching. The `popstate` event notifies you when the user navigates within the history, so _you_ can restore the previous view. That could f.e. mean, that you do the same AJAX request that you made to load that piece of content in the first place again – and _that_ is the point where the cache can come in: If you set up caching sensibly (from the server/HTTP perspective), then the browser will quickly realize (maybe after quick a conditional GET request), that he has that resource cached already and it’s still valid.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. That makes a lot of sense.